# How do I keep a machine learning model in memory on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Continuing from this discussion
[How to cache a large machine learning model in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213893/how-to-cache-a-large-machine-learning-model-in-flask)

It explains how to preload the model so it remains in memory for each rest api request.

However how do you deploy this on AWS?  I was considering AWS Lambda but quickly realized it may not support keeping the model running since it is a serverless service.

Does anyone know what is the recommended approach to deploying a model to AWS so that it is loaded only once for consumption by a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Since its a flask app, you could use Elastic Beanstalk (EB) for it as explained in AWS docs:

- [Deploying a flask application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html)

As part of EB environment creation you have to chose an instance type. So you have to chose the instance type with the amount of RAM that is suited for your model.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How does this solve the issue of keeping the model active so that subsequent api calls don't have to keep reloading it?

Comment: @erotavlas EB is not serverless like lambda, so you can keep your model in memory for as long as you want.